# Webform for Contact Information

Tags: webforms

What html code can I use to create a form for readers to submit their contact information (e.g., phone number, email address, etc.) and type a question?

Comment: Install [webform](http://drupal.org/project/webform) module so you can create form from admin panel

Answer (score 1):

If the Contact module doesn't suit your needs (comes with Drupal core and can be enabled on the Modules page), then your best option is to use the [Webform](http://drupal.org/project/webform) module.